# Can you recover the quantum numbers from just the shape of the spherical harmonic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, orbitals, spherical-harmonics

So I was wondering, in quantum physics beautiful graphs are introduced displaying spherical harmonics relying on the quantum numbers of $m$ and $l$. But is it possible to recover these quantum numbers given the shape of the spherical harmonic they produce?

For example, see the picture I attached. How would one go about finding the quantum numbers back from this? I have heard people find the number of nodes/planes but that looks to be extremely difficult in the below picture.

[image: Absolute real part of the harmonic.]

Comment: The spherical harmonics are set of complete functions on the surface of a sphere. You can use them to expand any sufficiently smooth function. To find the expansion coefficient of Ylm, you multiply your function by Ylm and integrate over the sphere.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, is it possible to read off $\ell$ and $m$ from the
shape of the spherical harmonic $Y_{\ell m}$.
The rules are not complicated:

- Number of plane nodes (containing the $z$-axis): $|m|$
- Number of cone-like nodes (around the $z$-axis): $\ell -|m|$

There is a nice interactive web page for [Visualization of Spherical Harmonics](http://icgem.gfz-potsdam.de/vis3d/tutorial).
You can choose values $\ell$ and $m$ to get an
image showing positive $Y_{\ell m}$ as red bumps,
negative $Y_{\ell m}$ as blue bumps, and also the nodes as thin lines.

Here is the image (with $\ell=6, m=3$) corresponding to the example image from your question:
[image]
<sub>(image generated using [Visualization of Spherical Harmonics](http://icgem.gfz-potsdam.de/vis3d/tutorial),
published by ICGEM Potsdam)</sub>